# Ho to make 404 error alert in axios react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello how can realize 404 error in axios?
Here's my code

```
  const WeatherFunc = async (city) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
              params: {
              q: city,
              units: 'metric',
              APPID: apikey,
          }
      });
      return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the response status in the axios promise

```js
axios.get(url, {
    //...
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 404) {
        // handle your 404
      }
      // ...
    }).catch(error => {
      // handle server error..
    })
```